# Qual o risco de um erro em uma página já carregada?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, try-catch

Possuo uma aplicação onde dados grandes em requisições AJAX são feitas, isso gera um certo *delay* ate posicionar os dados na página.

Preciso renderizar uma imagem onde seu *path* está um *array*. Ao meu perceber o *browser* tenta carregar a imagem uma vez mas o *array* não foi processado ainda, gerando um erro no console. O *browser* tenta encontrar a imagem de novo e nessa tentativa consegue pois o *array* já foi processado.

Para um usuário ele não veria problema nenhum, mas no console eu recebo um erro de

> Undefined

Com base nisso segue algumas dúvidas:

- **Devemos sempre eliminar os erros por mais que visualmente está tudo "*certo*"?**
- **A melhor forma de resolver a situação seria com um `Catch`?**
- **Existe alguma técnica ou tendencia a fazer um carregamento tardio?**

Comment: você precisa então carregar as imagens depois do array, se há esse dependência, isso é o mais correto a fazer

Comment: _"Ao meu perceber o browser tenta carregar a imagem uma vez mas o array não foi processado ainda"_ - seria o caso de corrigir para que não aconteça desta forma, já que você conseguiu diagnosticar o problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Devemos sempre eliminar os erros por mais que visualmente está tudo "certo"?

Não está tudo certo, está tudo funcionando, são coisas diferentes, então tem que fazer certo, porque o que está errado um dia te traz problemas.

[image: Fiat 147 caindo aos pedaços andando pelas ruas]

> A melhor forma de resolver a situação seria com um Catch?

Não, é a pior coisa a fazer em quase todas situações. Quando existe um erro você o conserta em vez de fazer de conta que ele não está lá. Pesquise aqui no site sobre o assunto. Exceção é o recurso de linguagem mais mal usado na programação hoje em dia. Poucas exceções devem ser tratadas em código. Não posso garantir poque não vi isso acontecendo e o código que faz desta forma, mas parece um erro de programação e não uma falha momentânea de ambiente, faça o código corretamente e não precisará disso. Use o `catch` para o caso de uma falha que foge do seu controle.

> Existe alguma técnica ou tendencia a fazer um carregamento tardio?

Sim, tem aqui no site e outros lugares e pelo jeito já sabe que chama-se *lazy loading*, não tem como responder em específico porque a pergunta é geral.

Comment: Heh, ótima imagem para ilustrar!